# Одинаковая высота в slick slider

Tags: jquery, slider, slick.js

Подскажите, как в карусели slick slider сделать одинаковую высоту для слайда slick-slide?  При этом слайд будет содержать изображения, у которых разная высота.
Т.е. нужно выровнять все изображения по нижнему краю слайда.
А сейчас у меня получается, что если у изображения маленькая высота, тогда это изображение прижато к верхнему краю. Я ставил для всех слайдов vertical-align: bottom, но не работает.

Comment: добавьте исходный код

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
vertical-align
```

работает с ячейками таблицы, а у вас скорее всего div контейнер, поэтому это свойство вам не поможет
попробуйте для общего родителя слайдов поставить `display: flex` и `align-items: flex-end`

Answer (score 1):

задать .slick-track {display: flex;}